# How does combining SHA256 with RIPE-MD160 compare to SHA256 + SHA-3?

Tags: cryptography, hash, sha256, bitcoin, sha-3

Bitcoin stores its addresses as a combined SHA256 + RIPE-MD160 hash. Is it correct to assume this is done to prevent a failure in the algorithm?

Since SHA3 was designed to be an alternative to SHA256, and uses a completely different methodology, would a SHA3(SHA2) or similar construction provide more security than RIPE-MD160(SHA2)?

What performance, security, and other tradeoffs are worth considering?

Are the SHAKE parameters of Keccak sufficient, or should I use non SHAKE parameters?

Answer (score 1):

When using SHA256 + RIPEMD-160, you are not only accumulating two different algorithm, but you are also varying your algorithm vendors, since SHA256 comes [from US NSA/NIST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) and RIPEMD-160 [comes from the european academic community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIPEMD).

While it is true that SHA-3 has not been directly designed by NSA, it went as a winner from NIST competition, and NSA is more or less involved in NIST, may it be for the good [or the worse](https://www.schneier.com/essays/archives/2007/11/did_nsa_put_a_secret.html). So, if you combine SHA256 + SHA-3, the two algorithm may be linked to the NSA and at least to NIST, so this may be seen as a potential weakness you can avoid by combining two algorithm with no link between them.